# Приложение для Убунту, блокирует экран каждые Х минут на Y минут и потом разблокирует

Tags: ubuntu, поиск-программ

Кто-нибудь подскажет приложуху для убунту 20.04, которая бы каждый час (условно) показывала бы какие-то обои или скринсейвер в течение 10 минут, а потом бы разблокировала бы экран? Цель - поддерживать режим работы за компом для глаз.

Я нашел несколько так называемых скринсейверов, но они для кейсов блокировки, когда пользователь отошел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта техника работы называется *Pomodoro Technique*. В Убунту 20 доступна программа [gnome-shell-pomodoro](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-pomodoro) (`apt install gnome-shell-pomodoro`)

Эта программа показывает уведомление когда  нужно сделать перерыв.

В настройках есть пункт Plugins, Там включи Custom actions.

Переходи обратно в настройки и в пунктах Пользовательские действия укажи для блокировки экрана

```
xdg-screensaver activate
```

и для разблокировки

```
xdg-screensaver reset
```

Можно добавить для блокировки после включения экрана ещё и блокировку добавив команду

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

Другие программы на эту тему ищи по слову Pomodoro

Comment: спасибо, попробую.